# DraftJs: How to insert html which have links in it?

Tags: javascript, html, draftjs

I am able to set content of editor from HTML string. But it skip anchor tag from it.

Here is code I am using to set state

```
let html = `Hello. I am <b>bolded</b> text with <a href="google.com"><span>GOOGLE</span></a> link.`;
let blocksFromHTML = convertFromHTML(html);
let state = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
  blocksFromHTML.contentBlocks,
  blocksFromHTML.entityMap
);
let editorState = EditorState.createWithContent(state);
editor.setState({editorState: editorState});
```

Can anybody suggest how to add clickable links in editor?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out this issue? https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/237 - If you include a valid protocol it should work - I tested your example but added `http://` to the beginning of the `href` and the conversion worked.

You also need to set up a CompositeDecorator for the link to show up properly in DraftJS, if you haven't already. There's an example here: https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/master/examples/draft-0-10-0/link/link.html